# "The property 'JournalEntryDetailsID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. "

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, c#-4.0, ado.net

I am trying to read the data from datagrid view  and insert into table in database.

The grid consists of nearly 10 rows. After the first row gets inserted,the loop shows the error "The property 'JournalEntryDetailsID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.", for the second row.

In this, 'JournalEntryDetailsID' is the primary key of the table.

Please check the bellow code:

```
   Dim AddJournalEntryDetails As New JournalEntryDetail

        For i As Integer = 0 To grdLedgerDetails.Rows.Count - 2
            If grdLedgerDetails.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = Nothing Then
                With AddJournalEntryDetails
                    .JournalEntryDetailsID = Guid.NewGuid
                    .JournalEntryID = JournalEntryID
                    .Date = dtDate.Value
                    .LedgerID = New Guid(grdLedgerDetails.Rows(i).Cells("LedgerName").Value.ToString)
                    .Narration1 = grdLedgerDetails.Rows(i).Cells("Narration1").Value.ToString
                    .Narration2 = grdLedgerDetails.Rows(i).Cells("Narration2").Value.ToString

                    If grdLedgerDetails.Rows(i).Cells("Debit").Value.ToString = 0 Then
                        .DebitAmount = 0
                    Else
                        .DebitAmount = grdLedgerDetails.Rows(i).Cells("Debit").Value.ToString
                    End If

                    If grdLedgerDetails.Rows(i).Cells("Credit").Value = Nothing Then
                        .CreditAmount = 0
                    Else
                        .CreditAmount = grdLedgerDetails.Rows(i).Cells("Credit").Value.ToString
                    End If
                    .IsActive = True
                    .IsDeleted = False
                    .IsRemovedByUpdate = False
                    .RowID = Guid.NewGuid
                    .CreatedDate = EntryDate
                    .EditedDate = EntryDate
                    .CreatedSessionID = ObjSysStatus.SessionId
                    .EditedSessionID = ObjSysStatus.SessionId
                    .OfflineMode = ObjSysStatus.OfflineStatus
                    .OfflineID = ObjSysStatus.OfflineID
                End With
                ObjSysStatus.ObjEntities.AddToJournalEntryDetails(AddJournalEntryDetails)
                ObjSysStatus.ObjEntities.SaveChanges()
            End If
        Next
```

I got the point that error shown was like 'primary key cant be updated'. But i am trying to insert each row as new row in the table.
Please help me out of this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code created only one `JournalEntryDetail` object and update properties of that object in every iteration, that's why you got the exception. Move `AddJournalEntryDetails` variable declaration within `For` loop so that new `JournalEntryDetail` object created in every iteration :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To grdLedgerDetails.Rows.Count - 2
    If grdLedgerDetails.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = Nothing Then
        Dim AddJournalEntryDetails As New JournalEntryDetail
        ........
        ........
    End If
Next
```